# Error while creating Scaled objects in AKS with Keda

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azureportal, keda

When trying to use scaled objects it fails with the error

> Failed to create the scaledobject 'azure-monitor-scaler'. Error:  (400) : ScaledObject is currently not yet supported in the portal.

I am using the following code as per their documentation. Still seem it is not supported by azure portal.

```
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azure-monitor-secrets
data:
  activeDirectoryClientId: test
  activeDirectoryClientPassword: test123
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: azure-monitor-trigger-auth
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: activeDirectoryClientId
      name: azure-monitor-secrets
      key: activeDirectoryClientId
    - parameter: activeDirectoryClientPassword
      name: azure-monitor-secrets
      key: activeDirectoryClientPassword
  # or Pod Identity, kind: Secret is not required in case of pod Identity
  podIdentity:
      provider: azure
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: azure-monitor-scaler
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: sample-dep
  minReplicaCount: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 10
  triggers:
  - type: azure-monitor
    metadata:
      resourceURI: Microsoft.Network/applicationgateways/ag
      tenantId: 22323-2321-2232-1212
      subscriptionId: 2323232323232323
      resourceGroupName: sample-rd
      metricName: AvgRequestCountPerHealthyHost
      metricFilter: BackendSettingsPool eq 'pool'
      metricAggregationInterval: "0:0:10"
      metricAggregationType: Average
      targetValue: "10"
    authenticationRef:
      name: azure-monitor-trigger-auth
```

Comment: check this github disscussion might be downgrading of keda version works : https://github.com/kedacore/keda/issues/1629

Comment: I have already installed Keda version 2.7 which should have solved issue according to discussion in above link

Comment: try with keda version 2.0 . it should work.

Comment: Also check this : https://github.com/kedacore/keda/discussions/2014

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the LA scaler is broken by changes in keda version 2.7.0.

You can try to run an older version of keda with LA scaler it should work for you.

You can do it by running the following command: `helm install keda kedacore/keda --version 2.0.0 --namespace keda`